# Spring MVC - unable to locate tag library for custom tag

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I keep getting an "JSPG0047E: Unable to locate tag library for uri /WEB-INF/tags" error on the following JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib prefix="my" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<my:custom-tag param1="${someVariable}" />
```

My tag looks like this:

```
<%@ tag body-content="empty"%>
<%@ attribute name="param1" required="true" type="java.lang.Object"%>
<dl>
    <dt>Name</dt>
    <dd>${param1.name}</dd>
</dl>
```

This is in a Spring MVC app I've deployed in a WAR in an EAR to WebSphere Application Server 7.  I don't know if it's a problem with the context-root, because the tags directory isn't at `localhost/WEB-INF/tags` but rather `localhost/myApp/WEB-INF/tags`, I think.  I have the following directory structure:

```
- src
    - main
        - webapp
            - WEB-INF
                - tags
                    - custom-tag.tag
                - views
                    - jspFileThatUsesTag.jsp
```

The deployment assembly for the WAR project has `/src/main/webapp` going to `/`, so `WEB-INF/tags` is getting put at the root of my app.

What am I doing wrong?  Trying to put a different value for `tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"` causes an error about the tag directory not starting with `WEB-INF/tags`.

Answer (score 1):

...It works.  I did a Project > Clean just on a lark, published again to the server from within Rational Application Developer, and now it has no problem with my tags directory or my custom tag.